# How to fix 'Unable to Load browser: null' (NPE) when running automated tests using cucumber and gherkin

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a selenium framework in Java which is using a DriverFactor class, Constant class, a ReadConfigFile class and a config.properities file to store relevant data in which I can call through the DriverFactory.

However, when I run a feature file, I get an error almost straight away citing, 'Unable to load browser: null'.

I believe this is happening as the config file isn't being read properly, so therefore returns 'null' and then fails. I just can't seem to be able to fix the issue.

I have added e.printstacktrace(); to try and get a better idea of where the issue is originating, but I'm yet to imply a fix.

DriverFactory.java

```
package utils;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class DriverFactory {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {

        try {
            // Read Config
            ReadConfigFile file = new ReadConfigFile();
            String browser = file.getBrowser();

            switch (browser) {

            /*
             * switch statement lets you select the browser you want
             */

            case "firefox":
                // code
                if (null == driver) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                }

                break;

            case "chrome":
                // code
                if (null == driver) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                }

                break;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("Unable to load browser: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }// finally {
            //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //}
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Constant. java

```
package utils;

public class Constant {

    /*
     * Config Property File 
     */

    public final static String CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY = "config.properties";

    public final static String CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";

    public final static String GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\geckondriver.exe";

}
```

ReadConfigFile.java

```
package utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ReadConfigFile {
    protected InputStream input = null;
    protected Properties prop = null;

    public ReadConfigFile() {
        try {
            ReadConfigFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
            prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(input);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getBrowser() {
        if (prop.getProperty("browser") == null)
            return "";
        return prop.getProperty("browser");
    }

}
```

config.properities

```
browser=chrome
```

Console/StackTrace print out

```
Feature: Log into account
  Existing user should be able to log into account using correct credentials

  Scenario Outline: Login to account with credentials         # C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/CucumberFramework/CucumberFramework/src/test/java/features/Login.feature:4
    Given user navigates to "<url>"
    When user clicks on the login portal button
    And User enters username "<username>"
    And User enters password "<password>"
    And User clicks on the login button
    Then user should be presented with validation "<message>"

    Examples: 
Unable to load browser: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at utils.ReadConfigFile.<init>(ReadConfigFile.java:15)
    at utils.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:16)
    at stepDefinitions.MasterHooks.setup(MasterHooks.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenarioOutline.run(CucumberScenarioOutline.java:46)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Unable to load browser: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at utils.ReadConfigFile.<init>(ReadConfigFile.java:15)
    at utils.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:16)
    at stepDefinitions.GenericWebSteps.user_navigates_to(GenericWebSteps.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenarioOutline.run(CucumberScenarioOutline.java:46)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)

  Scenario Outline: Login to account with credentials                 # C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/CucumberFramework/CucumberFramework/src/test/java/features/Login.feature:14
    Given user navigates to "http://www.webdriveruniversity.com"      # GenericWebSteps.user_navigates_to(String)
      java.lang.NullPointerException
        at stepDefinitions.GenericWebSteps.user_navigates_to(GenericWebSteps.java:21)
        at ✽.Given user navigates to "http://www.webdriveruniversity.com"(C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/CucumberFramework/CucumberFramework/src/test/java/features/Login.feature:5)

    When user clicks on the login portal button                       # GenericWebSteps.user_clicks_on_the_login_portal_button()
    And User enters username "tomdale"                                # GenericWebSteps.user_enters_a_username(String)
    And User enters password "testuser1"                              # GenericWebSteps.user_enters_a_password(String)
    And User clicks on the login button                               # GenericWebSteps.user_clicks_on_the_login_button()
    Then user should be presented with validation "validation failed" # GenericWebSteps.user_should_be_presented_with_validation(String)

Failed scenarios:
C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/CucumberFramework/CucumberFramework/src/test/java/features/Login.feature:14 # Scenario Outline: Login to account with credentials

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
6 Steps (1 failed, 5 skipped)
0m0.076s

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at stepDefinitions.GenericWebSteps.user_navigates_to(GenericWebSteps.java:21)
    at ✽.Given user navigates to "http://www.webdriveruniversity.com"(C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/CucumberFramework/CucumberFramework/src/test/java/features/Login.feature:5)
```

I expect either a chrome driver instance or gecko driver instance to load and my test to execute.

Actual results, I received 'Unable to load browser: null' error

Answer (score 0):

In your these lines

```
public class ReadConfigFile {
    protected InputStream input = null;
    protected Properties prop = null;

    public ReadConfigFile() {
        try {
            ReadConfigFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
            prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(input);
```

you have initialised `input` as null and then in `prop.load(input)`, you're loading a `input` which is still null. That is why there is a NPE.

Comment: Hi Demouser123,

So in this instance, what should the InputStream be set too?

Comment: What are you using it for?

Comment: Well I call the input in the Public ReadConfigFile method..

```
 public ReadConfigFile() {
  try {
   ReadConfigFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
   prop = new Properties();
   prop.load(input);
   
  }
```

This will then talk to the DriverFactory, which in turn will read the desired browser in my config file. But it's not pulling 'Chrome' from the config, instead it's setting to Null

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with a similar issue, I managed to work it out in the end.

So first of all, within the ReadConfigFile.java, within the try statement, you will want set the initialization of ReadConfig to input. As shown below..

```
    try {
        input = ReadConfigFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
        prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(input);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also, within your Constant.java class, set the CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY to the file path where your config.properties file is stored, like below:

```
package utils;

public class Constant {

    /*
     * Config Property File 
     */

    public final static String CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY = "properties\\config.properties";

    public final static String CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";

    public final static String GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\geckondriver.exe";

}
```

If you then run configurations on the chosen Feature file, it should create an instance of your chosen Web Driver and your test should run as normal.